# How to get data of current id on recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

How can i display this to Recyclerview? i already got the data of the id i want to display it on Recyclerview. i want to filter the data that depends on the current user.. btw i am using navigation drawer and it is on fragment.

[image: this is the logcat]

this is the logcat.

i want to the data of the given id to recyclerview. but the problem is it wont display. please help.. thanks in advance here is my code.

this is the AdapterApartment

```
public class AdapterApartment extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterApartment.ViewHolderApartment> {

private Context mCtx;
private ArrayList<Apartment> apartmentList = new ArrayList <>();

public AdapterApartment(Context mCtx, ArrayList <Apartment> apartmentList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.apartmentList = apartmentList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolderApartment onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_houses, null);
    return new ViewHolderApartment(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderApartment holder, int position) {
    Apartment apartment = apartmentList.get(position);


    holder.category.setText(apartment.getCategory());
    holder.apartmentname.setText(apartment.getApartmentname());
    holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(apartment.getPrice()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return apartmentList.size();
}

class ViewHolderApartment extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView category, apartmentname, price;

    public ViewHolderApartment(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
        apartmentname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
    }
}
```

}

```
private String url = Server.URL + "viewapartment.php";
private String url2 = Server.URL + "listapartment.php";


private ArrayList<Apartment> apartmentList = new ArrayList <>();
private AdapterApartment adapterApartment;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private String id;
private String username;
private int success;
TextView txt_id, txt_username;

private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

ProgressDialog pDialog;


public static LandlordAddApartment newInstance(String id, String username) {
    LandlordAddApartment fragment = new LandlordAddApartment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(TAG_ID, id);
    args.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        id = getArguments().getString(TAG_ID);
        username = getArguments().getString(TAG_USERNAME);
    }

}



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.landlord_add_apartment, container, false);

    txt_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.add_txt_id);
    txt_id.setText(id);
    txt_username = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.add_txt_username);
    txt_username.setText(username);






    checkUseriD(id);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapterApartment= new AdapterApartment(getActivity(), apartmentList);
    loadApartment();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterApartment);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddApartment.class);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return v;

}


protected boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (mNetworkInfo == null) ? false : true;


    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        return false;

    }
}

private void checkUseriD(final String id) {

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMessage("searching ...");
    showDialog();


    StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener <String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "get id Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();


            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                // Check for error node in json
                if (success == 1) {

                    Log.e("Success", jObj.toString());


                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            hideDialog();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map <String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map <String, String> params = new HashMap <String, String>();
            params.put("userID", id);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest1, tag_json_obj);

}
private void loadApartment() {

    String url;

    /*
    * Creating a String Request
    * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
    * The URL is defined in the second parameter
    * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
    * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
    *
    * */

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2, new Response.Listener <String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                //converting the string to json array object
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                //traversing through all the object
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    //getting product object from json array
                    JSONObject apartment = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    apartmentList.add(new Apartment(
                            apartment.getInt("userID"),
                            apartment.getString("Category"),
                            apartment.getString("apartmentName"),
                            apartment.getString("price_month")));
                }
                //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                AdapterApartment adapter = new 
          AdapterApartment(getContext(), apartmentList);
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
}



private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

this is the php. i dont know if my json code format is wrong.

```
<?php 



$server="localhost";
$user   = "root"; 
$password= ""; 
$database= "albayboardinghouse";

$connect = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password) or die ("connect failed!");
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Error!");

$userID = $_POST['userID'];

class emp{}

if (empty($userID)) { 
    $response = new emp();
    $response->success = 0;
    $response->message = "Error data"; 
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT userID, Category, apartmentName, price_month  FROM apartmentlocation WHERE userID = '".$userID."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);



    if (!empty($row)) {
        $response = new emp();
        $response->success = 1;
        $response->userID = $row["userID"];
        $response->Category = $row['Category'];
        $response->apartmentName = $row['apartmentName'];
        $response->price_month = $row['price_month'];
        die(json_encode($response));

        } 
        else{ 
        $response = new emp();
        $response->success = 0;
        $response->message = "Error getting Data";
        die(json_encode($response)); 
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: I don't really think you have understood what `RecyclerView` really is for. `RecyclerView`'s primary objective is to display a list of items on the screen and scrolling them if they surpass the screen space. You have only 1 item here. Can't see why you need a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @HamedMomeni im just asking on how to filter the data on on recyclerview with the id of the current user.. it doesnt mean i only want to use recyclerview for just 1 item.

Comment: Can you post AdapterApartment class?

Comment: @jelic98 updated :)

Comment: I have not understood the question correctly. Do you get the apartment name and price to be displayed or not?

Comment: @jelic98 yes they should be displayed as well.

Comment: But now, are they displaying alright?

Comment: @jelic98 no! it doesnt display the data of the current user

Comment: Well, should it display data of current user? You are using RecyclerView to dipslay apartments, not users.

Comment: @jelic98 i mean the apartments of the current user.. sorry for that :)

Comment: If you are sure that apartmentList hass correct data. You can use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in loadApartments()

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to filter the data in your recycler view. if thats the issue, there is inbuilt Filter method to filter the datas from inside recycler view adapter.

below is the code used to filter contacts using filter method...

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                contactListFiltered = contactList;
            } else {
                List<Contact> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Contact row : contactList) {

                    // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                    // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                    if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getPhone().contains(charSequence)) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

                contactListFiltered = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            contactListFiltered = (ArrayList<Contact>) filterResults.values;

            // refresh the list with filtered data
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

just check above code and change according to your need, as i cannot correctly figure your issue.
Thank you. :)